# Change the width of different td's according to text

Tags: html, css

I have created a table and now i wanted to change the width of td's depending on the text. but it is not effecting on td's. and If i change the width of first td then it also automatically change the width of next tr "td". How can i give different widths on different td's in html.Below is my code.

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;" width="150px"><span id="lblStockName"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;" width="30px">Bid:</td>
            <td><span id="lblBid"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Ask:</td>
            <td><span id="lblAsk"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Spot:</td>
            <td><span id="lblSpot"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Hi:</td>
            <td><span id="lblHi"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="lblLimit"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Last:</td>
            <td><span id="lblLast"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Ch:</td>
            <td><span id="lblCh"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Vol:</td>
            <td><span id="lblVol"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Low:</td>
            <td><span id="lblLow"></td>'
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, `width="150px"` is invalid, try `width="150"` or `style="width: 150px"` instead.

> If i change the width of first td then it also automatically change the width of next tr "td"

This is by design; to get different widths for each `<tr>`'s set of `<td>`'s, you'll have to nest tables.

---

**Edit**

If you're going to stay with your current layout, you should use `colspan` so that `<td>`'s are balanced:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder; width: 150px" colspan="13"><span id="lblStockName"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder; width: 30px">Bid:</td>
            <td><span id="lblBid"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Ask:</td>
            <td><span id="lblAsk"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Spot:</td>
            <td><span id="lblSpot"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Hi:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><span id="lblHi"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="lblLimit"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Last:</td>
            <td><span id="lblLast"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Ch:</td>
            <td><span id="lblCh"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Vol:</td>
            <td><span id="lblVol"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">Low:</td>
            <td><span id="lblLow"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: stealthyninja,  i have tried it out your first solution has worked by nesting the tables but not with the colspan. what do you suggest in that, either to use the nested tables or colspan, because with colspan it isn't working.

Comment: @Java_NewBie -- Use nested tables, if it's working for you and achieves what you want. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<table border="1" width="100%"> --> the whole table is 100%!
  <tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Savings</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td width="70%">January</td> --> then you chunk the td accordingly!
<td width="30%">$100</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>February</td>
<td>$80</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you add width in Feburary td you will not have any effect on the td, this example is from w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

Colspans are most probably your best bet. With these, you are not restricted to having the same column widths in each row. Please look at the sample below:

```
<table border="1" width="200">
    <tr>
        <td>pqr</td><td>stu</td><td>vwx</td><td>yz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">pqr</td><td>stu</td><td>vwx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pqr</td><td colspan="3">stu</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 11 pixel for each full width character then you can get the largest width spanned with:

```
$('.td-class').each(function(){length = (length < $(this).text().trim().length * 11 ? $(this).text().trim().length * 11 : length);});
```

Assign the width to cells

```
$('.td-class').each(function(){$(this).css( 'min-width', length + 'px' );});
```